# How to remove/hide export button in full screen view in highcharts-angular

Tags: javascript, highcharts

[image]

For Reference find the screenshot.
Already tried https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=42208 but still its not working.

Comment: Could you provide a live demo that illustrates your attempt to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by using following snippet

```
     let chart2FullScreen = true;
let chart1fullScreen = true;
```

document.addEventListener('fullscreenchange', (event) => {

```
  if (event.target['id'] === 'divId1') {
      Highcharts.charts[0].update({
      exporting: {
        buttons: {
          contextButton: {
            enabled: chart1FullScreen ? false : true
          }
        }
      }
    });
    chart1FullScreen = !chart1FullScreen ;
  } else if (event.target['id'] === 'divId2') {
    Highcharts.charts[1].update({
      exporting: {
        buttons: {
          contextButton: {
            enabled: chart2fullScreen ? false : true
          }
        }
      }

    });
    chart2fullScreen = !chart2fullScreen;
  }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

One way this could be done is using three things:

- [Document: fullscreenchange
  event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/fullscreenchange_event)

> `event` when transitioning into or out of the full-screen mode

- [document.fullscreenElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/fullscreenElement)

> read-only property to test whether full-screen mode is being used. `null` means its not.

- Hicharts `update` API to update properties/options of a chart on the fly.

**Javascript:** [fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/cju69eb7/)

```
let demochart = Highcharts.chart("container", {
  chart: {
    type: "column"
  },
  title: {
    text: "Monthly Average Rainfall"
  },
  credits: {
    enabled: false
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr"],
    crosshair: true
  },
  yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    title: {
      text: "Rainfall (mm)"
    }
  },
  tooltip: {
    headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
    pointFormat:
      '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
      '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} mm</b></td></tr>',
    footerFormat: "</table>",
    shared: true,
    useHTML: true
  },
  plotOptions: {
    column: {
      pointPadding: 0.2,
      borderWidth: 0
    }
  },
  series: [
    {
      name: "Tokyo",
      data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2]
    }
  ]
});

/*listening to full-screen change event*/
document.addEventListener("fullscreenchange", event => {
  demochart.update({
    exporting: {
      enabled: document.fullscreenElement ? false : true
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove the context menu

Remove the below module script from code

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
```

Or Disable the export

```
exporting: {
enabled: true
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/yy29pwda/

Comment: I don't want to remove the export option. When we click on VIEW FULL SCREEN inside export button we are unable to hide export button option inside print, viewfullscreen option. Is there any way to hide or remove export button inside print or view full screen.